# spring boot does not register entities in the depended projects java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity

Tags: java, entity, criteriabuilder

I have base entity

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
public class BaseAuditEntity extends BaseEntity {
      ...
}
```

and the entity below

```
package core.entities
@Entity
public class Customer extends BaseAuditEntity {
    ...
}
```

when I try to query database using criteria builder like below:

```
CriteriaQuery<BaseIdCodeDto> query =
    getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(BaseIdCodeDto.class);

Root<Customer> root = query.from(Customer.class);
```

it says:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not an
 entity: class core.entities.Customer; nested exception is
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity:
```

I dont have a `persistence.xml` file. I know that other projects are working without this file so how can I fix this? What is the problem?

`Customer` class is located in another project. I add maven dependency to the pom of the current project. The problem could be this, but I have no solution.

**I created `Customer` class in my current project. The error changed. This time it does not see one to one depended entities like `CustomerChannel`. This class is also located in the depended project and also annotated with `@Entity` as well. So why doesn't spring boot see it? I expect all the classes annotated with the `@Entity` should be registered as entities, but spring boot does not register entities in the depended projects. Am I wrong to expect this?**

It says

```
Customer.customerChannel references an unknown entity: 
core.entities.CustomerChannel
```

It looks like if I add all of the entities from the depended project to the current project, the problem will be fixed but I cant do it because there are multiple projects using the same entities.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: seems like you have imported the class wrong - make sure that you are importing your `Customer` class and not from some library

Comment: I have checked the package, it seems to be correct

Comment: and what is the import of the `@Entity` annotation?

Comment: Try to add annotation `@EntityScan( basePackages = {"your package - core.entities"} )` to your `ServerApplication` class

Comment: what do you mean by `ServerApplication` class?  is it @SpringBootApplication annotated class? @D.T

Comment: @D.T thanks dude you comment fixed the issue, why don't you post it as an answer? However, my other projects does not have `@EntityScan` tag, but they are still working. Is there any other way to fix the issue?

Comment: @ylmzzsy in that case I think your class package are not really in order, could you update the post with your hierarchy in your project?